# What is the solution of $a^2=b^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

How to solve $a^2=b^2$?

Should I consider if the number is negative or positive?

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: $(a^2-b^2) = (a+b)(a-b) = 0$, hence either $a=b$ or $a=-b$.

Answer (score 2):

$$a^2=b^2\implies a=\pm b$$ so they are either the same sign (or zero) or different sign
...

Answer (score 1):

The equation is equivalent to $a^2-b^2 = 0$ or $(a-b)(a+b) = 0$, hence all $a,b\in\mathbb R$ with $b=a$ or $b = -a$ are solutions.

Answer (score 0):

$$ a^2=b^2\Leftrightarrow |a|=|b| $$
$$ \Rightarrow a=b ~~~~~ \vee~~~~~ a=-b$$